# Why does @Cachable(...) work with @Bean return mock() but not with @MockedBean

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test, spring-bean, spring-cache

Why does the cache get filled with Values when using

```
@Autowired
ServiceXY serviceXY

@TestConfiguration
static class AppDefCachingTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ServiceXY ServiceXYMock() {
        return mock(ServiceXY.class);
    }
}
```

But not with

```
@MockBean
ServiceXY serviceXY
```

When using @MockBean i get a NullPointerException when accessing the cache values like that in my test:

```
@Autowired
ConcurrentMapCacheManager cmcm; 

@Test
void anTest(){
when(serviceXY.methodThatFillsCache(anyString()).thenReturn("ABC");

serviceXY.methodThatFillsCache("TEST1");

cmcm.getCache("Cachename").get("TEST1",String.class).equals("ABC");
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caching is implemented using a proxy that intercepts calls to the cacheable method. When you use `@MockBean`, Spring Boot [intentionally](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7243) disables proxying. One consequence of this is that no caching is performed. Someone [recently made the point that this isn't very well documented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28036#issuecomment-920959713) so we may update the docs in the future.

If you're want to test that caching is working as expected, you should either use a genuine implementation of your service, or create the mock yourself via a `@Bean` method as you have done in the first example in your question.

Comment: Thank you andy. I look in the javadocs that would be a greate place to point that out or maby i just oversaw it. I did know how to solve this problem already but i wanted to understand what happens in the background that made it much clearer.